# Rigid body constraints and animation

Tags: physics

I have two rigid bodies linked together with a constraint. The problem is I need to animate the second rigid body at one point in the simulation. But as soon as I turn on "animate" in the rigid body settings, it seems like the object is no longer reacting to physics.

So my question is this:
Is there a way to drive rigid bodies that have constraints with animation keyframes, while they also participate in the physics simulation?

Here's an animated gif to illustrate:
[image: constraint stops working]

Answer (score 2):

The animate checkbox itself can have keyframes.  You can have it controlled by the animation system at the start, then turn off the Animated checkbox with a keyframe and physics will take over.  This is a common technique for launching projectiles.